# Sitecore webforms for marketers save action

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore-workflow

For a webshop i'm using Sitecore Webforms For Marketers. There is a multiple server configuration with 2 Content Delivery Server(CDS) and 1 Content Management Server(CMS). On the CDS servers is no possibility to write data, so i have configured a webservice to forward the form data from the CDS to the CMS server.

What's the goal? There are 2 forms where a user can:

1. Post a review for a product at the products detail page
2. Post a review for a product and select the product in a dropdownlist at a global
   page

The problem is that i have less experience with Sitecore Webforms For Marketers. It's important that the review's parent item the right product is. I have read the [developer manual](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web_forms_for_marketers_v2_reference_usletter.pdf) and figured out there are several save actions, but not the one i prefer. Do I need to create a custom save action or is there a simple workaroud (e.g. with workflows)?

Thanks a lot!

Jordy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a save action that calls your web service and submits the data to your CM instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some questions. CM instance? How do i set the right parent item (product)? How do i map the right inputfield to the right templatefield? Do you have an example?

Comment: CM = CMS. In example 1, get the context item (your product) and pass it's ID to your service. That's the parent. In example 2, in your drop down of products, have each Value be the GUID for each product. Then do the same as before